# Save javascript object into file with break words

Tags: javascript

I have a big array of objects that contains a string property. When I save my object called data to a file in json, the string property came with breaks words like `"getElementsByTagName(\"track\")"`. I need to get like that: `"getElementsByTagName("track")"` without `\`.

my code:

```
       var jsonobj = JSON.stringify(data,null,'\t');
       fs.write('final8.json', jsonobj, 'w');
```

Comment: You can't because `"getElementsByTagName("track")"` is not valid json.

Comment: So how do I print it like getElementsByTagName("track")?

Comment: @TiagoCastro Can you use single quotes instead?

Comment: I cant because its a page content, my script just get the content..

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do. The resulting json with non escaped double qoutes would be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid escaping by using single quotes. For example you can replace " with ' using custom serializer.

```
var data = {test: 'getElementByTagName("track")'}

JSON.stringify(data, function(key,value) {
  if(typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.replace(/"/g, '\'')
  }
  return value
}, '\t');

"{
    "test": "getElementByTagName('track')"
}"
```